# 8-Puzzle using A* and Manhattan Distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, ai, sliding-tile-puzzle, a-star

I have developed this 8-puzzle solver using A* with manhattan distance. Appreciate if you can help/guide me regarding:
1. Improving the readability and optimization of the code.
2. I am using sort to arrange the priority queue after each state exploration to find the most promising state to explore next. Any way to optimize it.

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
import datetime as dt
import sys

# calculate Manhattan distance for each digit as per goal
def mhd(s, g):
    m = abs(s // 3 - g // 3) + abs(s % 3 - g % 3)
    return sum(m[1:])

# assign each digit the coordinate to calculate Manhattan distance
def coor(s):
    c = np.array(range(9))
    for x, y in enumerate(s):
        c[y] = x
    return c

# checking if the initial state is solvable via inversion calculation
def inversions(s):
    k = s[s != 0]
    tinv = 0
    for i in range(len(k) - 1):
        b = np.array(np.where(k[i+1:] < k[i])).reshape(-1)
        tinv += len(b)
    return tinv

# check user input for correctness
def all(s):
    set = '012345678'
    return 0 not in [c in s for c in set]

# generate board list as per optimized steps in sequence
def genoptimal(state):
    optimal = np.array([], int).reshape(-1, 9)
    last = len(state) - 1
    while last != -1:
        optimal = np.insert(optimal, 0, state[last]['board'], 0)
        last = int(state[last]['parent'])
    return optimal.reshape(-1, 3, 3)

# solve the board
def solve(board, goal):
    #
    moves = np.array(   [   ('u', [0, 1, 2], -3),
                            ('d', [6, 7, 8],  3),
                            ('l', [0, 3, 6], -1),
                            ('r', [2, 5, 8],  1)
                            ],
                dtype=  [  ('move',  str, 1),
                           ('pos',   list),
                           ('delta', int)
                           ]
                        )

    dtstate = [ ('board',  list),
                ('parent', int),
                ('gn',     int),
                ('hn',     int)
                ]

    goalc = coor(goal)
    # initial state values
    parent = -1
    gn     = 0
    hn     = mhd(coor(board), goalc)
    state = np.array([(board, parent, gn, hn)], dtstate)

    #priority queue initialization
    dtpriority = [  ('pos', int),
                    ('fn', int)
                    ]

    priority = np.array( [(0, hn)], dtpriority)
    #
    while True:
        priority = np.sort(priority, kind='mergesort', order=['fn', 'pos']) # sort priority queue
        pos, fn = priority[0]                   # pick out first from sorted to explore
        priority = np.delete(priority, 0, 0)    # remove from queue what we are exploring
        board, parent, gn, hn = state[pos]
        board = np.array(board)
        loc = int(np.where(board == 0)[0])      # locate '0' (blank)
        gn = gn + 1                             # increase cost g(n) by 1

        for m in moves:
            if loc not in m['pos']:
                succ = deepcopy(board)          # generate new state as copy of current
                succ[loc], succ[loc + m['delta']] = succ[loc + m['delta']], succ[loc]   # do the move

                if ~(np.all(list(state['board']) == succ, 1)).any():    # check if new (not repeat)
                    hn = mhd(coor(succ), goalc)                         # calculate Manhattan distance
                    q = np.array(   [(succ, pos, gn, hn)], dtstate)     # generate and add new state in the list
                    state = np.append(state, q, 0)
                    fn = gn + hn                                        # calculate f(n)
                    q = np.array([(len(state) - 1, fn)], dtpriority)    # add to priority queue
                    priority = np.append(priority, q, 0)

                    if np.array_equal(succ, goal):                      # is this goal state?
                        print('Goal achieved!')
                        return state, len(priority)

    return state, len(priority)


#################################################
def main():
    print()
    goal    =  np.array( [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0] )
    string = input('Enter board: ')

    if len(string) != 9 or all(string) == 0:
        print('incorrect input')
        return

    board = np.array(list(map(int, string)))
    if (inversions(board) % 2 != 0):
        print('not solvable')
        return

    state, explored = solve(board, goal)
    print()
    print('Total generated:', len(state))
    print('Total explored: ', len(state) - explored)
    print()
    # generate and show optimized steps
    optimal = genoptimal(state)
    print('Total optimized steps:', len(optimal) - 1)
    print()
    print(optimal)
    print()


################################################################
# Main Program

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Since all possible \$f\$ values are from the set \$\{ 0, 1, \dots, c \}\$, where \$c\$ is rather small (probably less than 100 for 8-puzzle), you could use so called _Dial's_ heap: basically, you map each \$f\$ value to the list of nodes with that very value. In order to remove the minimum, scan the array from beginning to end, and return some node of the first non-empty list of nodes. See, for example, http://www.diku.dk/PATH05/GoldbergSlides.pdf page 45.

Comment: What does this do? `~(np.all(list(state['board']) == succ, 1)).any()`. I know that `(np.all(list(state['board']) == succ, 1)).any()`
returns a Boolean. So what does `~` do? I bet it's not what you're thinking...

Comment: @JoeWallis the statement `(np.all(list(state['board']) == succ, 1)).any()` returns a boolean True if any instance of state contains same values as succ. with ~ it turns to False, meaning if the succ contains a state that is not already in the queue, then add it to the queue. this is what i think it does and this is the functionality that i have implemented.

Comment: A* and TTT is equevalent

Comment: @ArturMustafin what's TTT? can u pl elaborate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't import things you don't use.
   You can safely remove `dt` and `sys`.
2. Don't overwrite builtins. `all` is already a function, and your implementation is more `is_anagram`.
3. When using Booleans use things for Booleans.

   ```
    # What are you on about 0 (the number) is never in.
    return 0 not in [c in s for c in set]

    # What you should use
    return False not in [c in s for c in set]

    # This can be better worded as:
    # And remove `__builtin__` if you stop shadowing `all`.
    return __builtin__.all(c in s for c in set)
   ```

   But then there is the usage of the bitwise not `~`.

   ```
    >>> bool(~True), ~True
    (True, -2)
    >>> bool(~False), ~False
    (True, -1)
    >>> bool(~-1), ~-1
    (False, 0)
   ```

   Yes `~(np.all(list(state['board']) == succ, 1)).any()` is always True. Instead use `not`.
4. Use fewer comments. And if you are to use comments, use pre-line rather than inline.

   ```
    # ugly
    gn = gn + 1 # increase cost g(n) by 1

    # better
    # increase cost g(n) by 1
    gn = gn + 1

    # Best (As we all understand addition.)
    gn += 1
   ```
5. Use less intermediary variables. And remove unused ones.

   ```
    # Bad
    m = abs(s // 3 - g // 3) + abs(s % 3 - g % 3)
    return sum(m[1:])

    # Good
    return sum((abs(s // 3 - g // 3) + abs(s % 3 - g % 3))[1:])

    # Bad
    pos, fn = priority[0]

    # Good
    pos, _ = priority[0]

    # Best
    pos = priority[0][0]
   ```
6. Use less whitespace. In the Python community whitespace is pretty important.
   The language itself ingrains good practice of well tabbed code.
   But we also discourage useless whitespace, or whitespace that impairs readability.

   ```
    # Bad
    moves = np.array(   [   ('u', [0, 1, 2], -3),
                        ('d', [6, 7, 8],  3),
                        ('l', [0, 3, 6], -1),
                        ('r', [2, 5, 8],  1)
                        ],
            dtype=  [  ('move',  str, 1),
                       ('pos',   list),
                       ('delta', int)
                       ]
                    )

    # Good
    moves = np.array(
        [
            ('u', [0, 1, 2], -3),
            ('d', [6, 7, 8],  3),
            ('l', [0, 3, 6], -1),
            ('r', [2, 5, 8],  1)
        ],
        dtype=[
            ('move',  str, 1),
            ('pos',   list),
            ('delta', int)
        ]
    )
   ```
7. Pick better variable names. We're not all mathematicians, and even if we were `gn` is of no help to understand the program.
   `parent` on the other hand is a good variable name.
8. The function `all` should be removed. As an alternate you can also just do an anagram check on it. `sorted(a) == sorted(b)`
9. `inversions` can make use of `sum` to reduce noise.
10. Reduce the amount of unused items in your arrays, currently the boards `parents` and `hn` are never used.
11. You can use a default dict rather than `np.all(list(state['board']) == succ, 1).any()`
    to check if you have already used found the board.

    This is good as for the input `012345678` you get:

    ```
    Total generated: 2057
    Total explored:  1305

    Total optimized steps: 22
    ```

    With `defaultdict` you can check the contents in `O(1)`, where you would have to check in `O(n)` with `np.all(...)`.

So I would use:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy
from collections import defaultdict

def mhd(s, g):
    return sum((abs(s // 3 - g // 3) + abs(s % 3 - g % 3))[1:])

def coor(s):
    c = np.array(range(9))
    for x, y in enumerate(s):
        c[y] = x
    return c

def solve(board, goal):
    moves = np.array(
        [
            ('u', [0, 1, 2], -3),
            ('d', [6, 7, 8], 3),
            ('l', [0, 3, 6], -1),
            ('r', [2, 5, 8], 1)
        ],
        dtype=[
            ('move', str, 1),
            ('pos', list),
            ('delta', int)
        ]
    )

    STATE = [
        ('board', list),
        ('parent', int),
        ('gn', int),
        ('hn', int)
    ]

    PRIORITY = [
        ('pos', int),
        ('fn', int)
    ]

    previous_boards = defaultdict(bool)

    goalc = coor(goal)
    hn = mhd(coor(board), goalc)
    state = np.array([(board, -1, 0, hn)], STATE)
    priority = np.array( [(0, hn)], PRIORITY)
    
    while True:
        priority = np.sort(priority, kind='mergesort', order=['fn', 'pos'])
        pos = priority[0][0]
        priority = np.delete(priority, 0, 0)
        board = state[pos][0]
        gn = state[pos][2] + 1
        loc = int(np.where(board == 0)[0])

        for m in moves:
            if loc not in m['pos']:
                succ = deepcopy(board)
                delta_loc = loc + m['delta']
                succ[loc], succ[delta_loc] = succ[delta_loc], succ[loc]
                succ_t = tuple(succ)

                if previous_boards[succ_t]:
                    continue

                previous_boards[succ_t] = True

                hn = mhd(coor(succ_t), goalc)
                state = np.append(
                    state,
                    np.array([(succ, pos, gn, hn)], STATE),
                    0
                )
                priority = np.append(
                    priority,
                    np.array([(len(state) - 1, gn + hn)], PRIORITY),
                    0
                )

                if np.array_equal(succ, goal):
                    return state, len(priority)

def inversions(s):
    k = s[s != 0]
    return sum(
        len(np.array(np.where(k[i+1:] < k[i])).reshape(-1))
        for i in range(len(k) - 1)
    )

def genoptimal(state):
    optimal = np.array([], int).reshape(-1, 9)
    last = len(state) - 1
    while last != -1:
        optimal = np.insert(optimal, 0, state[last]['board'], 0)
        last = int(state[last]['parent'])
    return optimal.reshape(-1, 3, 3)

def main():
    print()
    goal = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0])
    string = input('Enter board: ')
    board = np.array(list(map(int, string)))

    if sorted(string) != sorted('012345678'):
        print('incorrect input')
        return
    if inversions(board) % 2:
        print('not solvable')
        return

    state, explored = solve(board, goal)
    optimal = genoptimal(state)

    print((
        'Goal achieved!\n'
        '\n'
        'Total generated: {}\n'
        'Total explored:  {}\n'
        '\n'
        'Total optimized steps: {}\n'
        '{}\n'
        '\n'
    ).format(len(state), len(state) - explored, len(optimal) - 1, optimal))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: this is great stuff. taken note of all the points and implemented. only change is i had to put `succ = numpy.empty_like(board)` inside the moves loop as it was behaving strangely. thanks for highlighting use of ~ (if i had placed the bet would have lost it). is there any improvement u would suggest on the use of sort or the `np.all(list(state['board']) == succ, 1).any()` check.

Comment: @AbdulQadir No problem, I didn't want to mess with NumPy too much as I didn't have a working install of it. (I made the 'bet', as I was going to write an answer, but that one line was well odd). As for those two things, I can look into it, I doubt I can get the sort better, maybe use a different algorithm, and I don't know if it works but `np.all(state['board'] == succ, 1).any()` is as far as I know the best. I'll get numpy and do some changes, and will update my answer if there's anything good!

Comment: one thing i was wondering. why have you changed `succ = deepcopy(board)` to `succ = np.empty_like(board)` `np.copyto(succ, board)`. is it because of the additional library requirement with deepcopy or some other consideration.

Comment: @AbdulQadir I replaced `deepcopy` solely because IMO you don't need it. If you want to know why I chose those functions, then it was due to this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6431973

Comment: @AbdulQadir I added `deepcopy` back due to the same reason that you put it there. Without `deepcopy` my code would frequently raise errors, due to shallow copying.

Comment: yesterday i missed the further changes you made. the use of `defaultdict` has enhanced the performance exponentially. never used it before. i will explore it further.

Comment: i am working on using argmin() which can be one efficient way to replace the sort(). the code would become `smallest = priority['totalcost'].argmin()` `pos = priority[smallest][0]` `priority = np.delete(priority, smallest, 0)`. will do some checking and share the results.

Comment: i noticed that the first board (initial state) is not getting saved in the previous_boards. i think we should add `board_t = tuple(board)` `previous_boards[board_t] = True` before the iteration begins.

Answer (score 0):

I found two issues when I tested the code:

1. It gives "not solvable" for actual solvable cases like 203164875 as input.
2. For many cases that I tried (for example 876543210 or 013572468), the program gets stuck in an infinite loop.